# Can't click on MacOS Utilities

Tags: macos, trackpad, utilities

I'm in recovery-mode ... MacBook Pro (Catalina) ... I wanna get into Terminal-window to run a command, and I can use the trackpad to move the cursor around ... but I can't select an option in the Utilities menu? Why is that?

I tried to move around using the `tab` key and then selecting using `space-bar` ... but the menu is not selectable using the tab-button

Comment: Is this in Recovery mode? What Mac? What OS? What is your objective?

Comment: Yes in recovery-mode ... MacBook Pro (Catalina) ... I wanna get into `Terminal-window` to run a command

Comment: And the trackpad works normally otherwise? What year MBP? Models from 2014 and earlier have a 'real' click; later ones simulate a click with haptic feedback. You can normally select the menubar with CTRL F2.

Comment: Do you have tap to click enabled on your trackpad usually and try to use it that way? In recovery mode the standard is to actually have to press down on the trackpad to make it click.

Comment: @benwiggy yes! ... it's this **real** click thing ... I wasn't aware of that, I was using the normal touch-click ... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lizzan yes you're right ... it's this `hard-press` aka `real-press` ... thank you!

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli The information you have provided in comments should be edited into the question. Questions should include all the information needed to provide an answer as comments can and often will be deleted.

Comment: Excellent, I just added an answer about the clicks. It's caught me off-guard several times as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in Recovery mode, the trackpad works in press to click mode. If you're used to tap to click, this might come as a surprise and make you think it's not working properly. Try pressing down on the trackpad to actually get the feedback of a click and see if that works.